# Chart.js donut chart remains grey - no color

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts, chart.js

I have a donut chart being created by chart.js as follows:

```
        <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 320px; width: 320px">
            <canvas id="hoursFEContainer"></canvas>
        </div>
```

I require chart.js as follows (downloaded from npm):-

```
require('chart.js');
```

Then in a relevant function I instantiated Chart.js as follows:-

```
var distinctFeeEarners = ['MEH', 'IHM'];
var totalHoursByFE = [0.8, 0.7];
        var chartdata = {
                        labels: distinctFeeEarners,
                        datasets : [
                            {
                                label: 'Fee Earner',
                                data: totalHoursByFE
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    var ctx = $("#hoursFEContainer");

                    var donutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'doughnut',
                        backgroundColor:
                        ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'],                     
                        data: chartdata
                    });
```

The chart displays with the correct data, but the donut does not have any colours?

Whats wrong?

**EDIT: Beyond stupid, backgroundColor needs to be in datasets not in new Chart. Nevermind.**

Answer (score 1):

Set the **forceOverride** option to **true** in the Chart options like this. (If you're using React)

```
<Doughnut
    data={data}
    options={{
      plugins: {
        colors: {
          forceOverride: true,
        },
        legend: {
          position: "right",
        },
      },
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you define `backgroundColor` at the wrong place. It's a [dataset property](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#dataset-properties), hence needs to be defined inside the `dataset`.

```js
var distinctFeeEarners = ['MEH', 'IHM'];
var totalHoursByFE = [0.8, 0.7];
var chartdata = {
  labels: distinctFeeEarners,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Fee Earner',
    data: totalHoursByFE,
    backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)']
  }]
};

var donutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('hoursFEContainer'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: chartdata
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 320px; width: 320px">
  <canvas id="hoursFEContainer"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I have charts without any background and I have the same problem. Worst than that happens and fix it self on page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem with ng2-charts

What did it for me was not pre-initializing dataset.
Prevously i would declare empty array

```
public data: MultiDataSet = [];
```

then after backend request resolves i would assign new value

```
const dataset: Array<number> = new Array();
response.items.map(result => {
    dataset.push(result);
  });
this.data =  [dataset];
```

This would print doughnut chart but without color. Everything was gray.
Simply not preinitializing MultiDataSet like this fixes things

```
public data: MultiDataSet; //=[];
```